# How to implement a filter that narrows down the current search result by tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, e-commerce, shopify, liquid

So my client would like to have filtering options available for their recipes (which is a blog consisting of recipe articles). So far I'm able to allow the user to search for recipes based on meal type categories such as "All", "Breakfast", "Lunch", and "Dinner" by making each option a hyperlink by adding "blogs/recipes/tagged/breakfast" after the website name. Now here's where I'm having trouble, I would like to have radio box options such as "gluten free" or "paleo" that allow the user to narrow down the current search result even further. So for example, if a user clicked "Breakfast" and wanted to narrow down the current recipes shown, he could just click one of the options such as "gluten free" to do so.

I already have all the radio box options laid out where I would like them to under the meal type links. However, I have no idea how to create this filtering functionality that would narrow down the current recipe articles shown, could somebody please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="div-container" style = "display: flex; width: 45%; height: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

   <div class = "filter-content"> 
     <p class = "meal-type">Meal Type</p>
     <ul>
       <!-- Meal Types Go Here -->
       <li class = "meal-item"><a href="https://website.com/blogs/recipes">All Recipes</a></li>
       <li class = "meal-item"><a href="https://website.com/blogs/recipes/tagged/breakfast">Breakfast</a></li>
       <li class = "meal-item">Lunch</li>
       <li class = "meal-item"><a href="https://website.com/blogs/recipes/tagged/dinner">Dinner</a></li>
       <li class = "meal-item"><a href="https://website.com/blogs/recipes/tagged/snack">Snacks</a></li>
       <li class = "meal-item"><a href="https://website.com/blogs/recipes/tagged/dessert">Dessert</a></li>
     </ul>

     <p class = "filter-by">Filter by</p>
     <!-- Filter Options Go Here -->  
     <input type="radio" id="RecipeFilterOptions" name="recipe[FilterOptions]" value="beet powder"/> beet powder
     <br>
     <input type="radio" id="RecipeFilterOptions" name="recipe[FilterOptions]" value="easy"/> easy
     <br>
     <input type="radio" id="RecipeFilterOptions" name="recipe[FilterOptions]" value="gluten free"/> gluten free
     <br>
     <input type="radio" id="RecipeFilterOptions" name="recipe[FilterOptions]" value="paleo"/> paleo
   </div>
```

Comment: Please show your code that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

- creating a new endpoint that includes only the searches manually (not maintainable)
- or
- do you have a datastore which contains all of this information and are you simply filtering to display?

We need to see the data itself, as well as how you're currently filtering to be able to properly help, but here's a crude example for filtering.

```js
const meals = [{
    name: 'chicken parmesan',
    mealType: ['dinner'],
    attributes: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'bacon',
    mealType: ['breakfast', 'lunch', 'dinner'],
    attributes: [],
  },
  {
    name: 'uncooked rock',
    mealType: ['dinner'],
    attributes: ['paleo'],
  },
  {
    name: 'uncooked spinach',
    mealType: ['breakfast'],
    attributes: ['paleo']
  }
]

const filterMeals = (opts) => {
  const {
    mealType,
    attributes
  } = opts;
  let filteredMeals = meals
  if(mealType) {
    filteredMeals = filteredMeals.filter(obj => obj.mealType.includes(mealType));
  }
  if (attributes) {
    for (let i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
      filteredMeals = filteredMeals.filter(obj => obj.attributes.includes(attributes[i]))
    }
  }
  console.log(filteredMeals);
}

filterMeals({
  mealType: 'dinner',
  attributes: ['paleo'],
});

filterMeals({
  mealType: 'dinner',
})

filterMeals({
  attributes: ['paleo'],
})
```